# javascript recursive class: undefined method

Tags: javascript, class, recursion, promise

I have a JavaScript class that is meant to help deal with promises. First you add functions to an array, then it executes them pops them and calls itself to do the next one.  At the end of the array it resolves that promise.  My hope was to then propagate the resolution all the way up the stack of recursive calls.  This will allow you to force multiple asynchronous functions to run sequentially using a simple set of commands.  furthermore employ logic to modify the flow of the ansync functions.

```
function Sequencer() {

    this.functionSequence = [];

    this.addFunction = function (func) {
        this.functionSequence.push(func);
    }
    this.getFunctionSequence = function () {
        return functionSequence;
    }
    this.executeAll = function () {
        var functionList = this.functionSequence;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if (functionList.length > 0) {
            functionList[0]().then(function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    functionList.splice(0, 1);
                    executeAll().then(function (resultInner) {
                        if (resultInner == true) {
                            deferred.resolve(true);
                        } else {
                            deferred.resolve(false);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    functionList = [];
                    deferred.resolve(false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(true);
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

I am getting ReferenceError: 'executeAll' is undefined
in this script, on the recursive call line "executeAll' just after the splice

the first function in the array is being executed(I was testing it with a modal pop up) and when it resolves it hits the splice, then it throws the error right on the executeAll line. Am I defining the function incorrectly?  Am I calling it correctly as a recursive function?

Comment: use `this.executeAll` - assuming `this` will be correct, which it wont, so you'll need to account for that as well ... something like var self = this at the top of executeAll, then call self.executeAll ... however, this code can be simplified using Array's `reduce` method

Comment: that was it!  could you please enter that as an answer and I will choose it.  Could you also explain a little bit more about why "this" didn't work?  I don't quite understand why we had to put in into a local variable first, seems kinda silly.

Comment: Just use `compose` and write a `bind` function for converting the functions into Promise accepting ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `this.executeAll` - assuming `this` will be correct, which it wont, so you'll need to account for that as well ... something like `var self = this` at the top of executeAll, then call `self.executeAll`

```
this.executeAll = function() {
    var functionList = this.functionSequence;
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var self = this; // save reference to this
    if (functionList.length > 0) {
        functionList[0]().then(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                functionList.splice(0, 1);
                // need to use self here because "this" is not the "this" we want
                self.executeAll().then(function(resultInner) {
                    if (resultInner == true) {
                        deferred.resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        deferred.resolve(false);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                functionList = [];
                deferred.resolve(false);
            }
        });
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

The reason `this` is not the `this` you "want" is due to how `this` works in javascript - there is plenty on info  on stack exchange about using `this` - I'll find and link a good answer shortly

---

I offer this alternative code

```
this.executeAll = function() {
    return this.functionSequence.reduce(function(promise, item) {
        return promise.then(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                return item();
            }
            else {
                throw "Fail"; // throw so we stop the chain
            }
        });
    }, Promise.resolve(true))
    .then(function(result) {
        this.functionSequence = []; // clear out the added functions
        return true; // fulfilled value is true as per original code
    }.bind(this), function(err) {
        this.functionSequence = []; // clear out the added functions
        if (err == "Fail") {
            return false; // convert the "Fail" to a fullfilled value of false as per original code
        }
        else {
            throw err; // any other error - re-throw the error
        }
    }.bind(this))
};
```

Comment: I can't find a good explanation of the behaviour of `this` - search SO for an explanation. I also added alternative code for `executeAll` - which is "cleaner" in my opinion (and I think it behaves as per your code)